# How to connect to a Filemaker Database with ODBC?

Tags: odbc, connection-string, filemaker

I'm trying to find out how to connect to a FileMaker Pro 9 Database file (*.fp7) with ODBC. I followed the manual and installed the ODBC driver which now shows up as "DataDirect 32bit SequeLink 5.5".

However I can't find any instructions on **how** to connect to the Database File. I want to use LibreOffice Base (and maybe later on create my own app) to access Filemaker tables.

Any help would be appreciated! (Please note that I'm new to Filemaker as well as to ODBC)

Comment: I don't know if this is the manual you are talking about, or not. If not, you may find Chapter 3 helpful: http://www.filemaker.com/products/filemaker-pro/docs/9/fm9_odbc_jdbc_guide_en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You need the ActualTech software to connect to the database: http://www.actualtech.com/scenario_ess_setup.php

I don't know if it is down compatible with FileMaker 9 but you might want to upgrade to FileMaker 13 at this point.

They guys at ActualTech are also very helpful.

Once you installed it, you can set up a DSN in the ODBC manager.